# How do I validate a TextField component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I visited the Material UI Components documentation for TextField hoping to see an example of validation in action, but sadly they only show the appearance of the invalid TextField and not the code involved to do an actual validation.  The docs say "*The **error** prop toggles the error state.* "  But what does that mean?  What am I supposed to do with it?

I'm trying to do some validation on fields like e-mail address, postal code etc.  I don't need help with checking the field is correct (i.e. regular expressions)  I need to just see the framework or building blocks of the code involved to do the validation.

This is the form component I have so far

```
import './Form.css';
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { Container, Box, Stack, Grid, Button, ButtonBase } from '@mui/material';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';

function Form() {

  return (
    <div className="Form">
        <div >
              <Divider variant="middle" />
              <form >
                <Stack direction="column" spacing={2}>
                  <Stack direction="column" spacing={2}>
                  <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                                       
                        <TextField size="small" sx={{ width: '50%' }} label="First Name" variant="outlined" required />
                        <TextField size="small" sx={{ width: '50%' }} label="Last Name" variant="outlined" required />
                       
                    </Box>
                    <TextField size="small" label="Postal Code" variant="outlined" required />
                    <TextField size="small"  label="E-Mail" variant="outlined" required />
                  </Stack>

                  <Stack direction="column" spacing={2}>
                    <TextField size="small" label="Subject" multiline rows={1} required />
                    <TextField size="small" label="Message" multiline rows={7} required />
                    <TextField size="small" label="Additional Comments" multiline rows={7} required />
                    <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
                      <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" sx={{ width: 100, backgroundColor: '#0092d6' }}>
                          Send
                        </Button>
                       
                      </Stack>
                    </Grid>
                  </Stack>
                </Stack>
              </form>

            </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: There are many possible approaches for doing form validation. The place to start is to determine how you would do the validation if you were using a simple `<input type="text"/>` instead of `TextField`. If you can show your preferred validation approach for that case, then someone could help demonstrate how to use that approach with `TextField`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell if I had to do it myself, on the button onClick I'd call a function to validate each input on the form, define useState props that represent isValid state for each input in my component,  and in the validation function set the error property on each of the TextFeilds that are wrong based on their state. I thought material UI had something built in but it doesn't appear it does.  I'm currently looking into libraries like react-hook-form.

Comment: MUI does not have any validation logic built in. It just handles the styling of the error state and placement of validation text (via helperText).

Comment: @RyanCogswell looks like someone created what I was looking for, https://github.com/dohomi/react-hook-form-mui

Answer (score 4):

The **error** prop on **TextField** accepts a boolean, so pass it anything that returns true or false. This will highlight the input and helperText message in red, indicating that there is an error

Use this in conjunction with **helperText**, which accepts a string.

```
function ErrorDemo() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("error");

  // Memo that returns true if value is "error"
  const hasError = React.useMemo(() => value === "error", [value]);

  // Memo that returns a helper message if value is "error" or a blank string if not
  const getHelperText = React.useMemo(
    () => (value === "error" ? "Value cannot be 'error'" : ""),
    [value]
  );

  function handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <TextField
      label="Demo Textfield"
      value={value}
      helperText={getHelperText}
      onChange={handleChange}
      error={hasError}
    />
  );
}
```